# change absolute path for subfolder htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, path

Is there a way you can change the absolute path for a subfolder via .htaccess?

My dillema:

Site URL is `http://localhost/build`

But When I use an absolute path like:

```
<script src="/assets/script.js"></script>
```

OR

```
<a href="/projects/">Projects</a>
```

The URL changes to `http://localhost/assets/script.js` and `http://localhost/projects`

I need it them to be
`http://localhost/build/assets/script.js` and `http://localhost/build/projects`

Absolute paths need to be used for this project.

Comment: Not possible without capturing the page responses and modifying them on the fly. Either add `/build` to the paths or use relative paths

Comment: @arco444 I got it to work, see answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I placed the following in the .htaccess in the root directory i.e. `http://localhost`. Works for both `href` and `src` tags.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/build
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /build/$0 [L]
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: It doesn't look like your 2nd `RewriteCond` directive is required. `REQUEST_URI` always starts with a slash - so this is _always_ true. (?)